# git-merge is not respecting mergeoptions

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to configure my local git to always use --squash when merging into `develop` branch. As many recommendations suggest I tried `git config branch.develop.mergeoptions "–-squash"` but it seems to have no effect:

```
> git checkout -b test_branch
> touch 1 2
> git add 1
> git commit -m "Added 1"
> git add 2
> git commit -m "Added 2"
> git checkout develop
> git merge test_branch
Updating e258d21..90a41ec
Fast-forward
 1 | 0
 2 | 0
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 1
 create mode 100644 2
```

My expectation is that result of `git merge test_branch` would be exactly the same as for `git merge --squash test_branch`. But it obviously not true: merge pulls in both commits from `test branch` without any attempt to squash them.

What am I missing?

Dump of local config looks like this

```
$ git config --local --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=git@yyy.com:repo/repo.git
gitflow.branch.master=master
gitflow.branch.develop=develop
gitflow.prefix.feature=feature/
gitflow.prefix.release=release/
gitflow.prefix.hotfix=hotfix/
gitflow.prefix.support=support/
gitflow.prefix.versiontag=
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.develop.remote=origin
branch.develop.merge=refs/heads/develop
branch.develop.rebase=true
branch.develop.mergeoptions=--ff-only –-squash
user.name=User Name
user.email=xxx@yyy.com
log.mailmap=true
push.default=simple
```

Comment: Waht returns `git config --local --list` ?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I updated the post to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made typo when passing options in git config. Try this: `git config branch.develop.mergeoptions "--squash"` Did it help?

Comment: Oh. My. God. For some reason I had a long dash (– instead of -) in --squash. Copy-pasting your line worked and helped me to see this problem.